# Медленная загрузка ubuntu 15.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, долгая-загрузка

Добрый день. Такой вопрос: я установил java на компьютер плюс у меня сглючила программа Mathematica и я решил перезагрузить компьютер. В итого он стал загружаться около 10 мин. И теперь так загружается постоянно, Хотя раньше загружался секунд за 5. При загрузки компьютера он останавливается на   значке ubuntu, а потом все происходит нормально. Как исправить и что произошло?

Comment: в момент когда оно тупит, можно нажать esc и там будет виден текстовый лог. А там будет яснее.

Answer (score 1):

Если зависает во время загрузки, можно нажать Esc при загрузке и посмотреть что в консоли происходит, может диски проверяет, например. Или отключить "тихий" режим загрузки системы: убрать параметр `quiet` у Grub. А так лог загрузки смотреть, что происходит:

```
/var/log/boot.log
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

Comment: а что может быть в этом случае полезного в логах `X`? Там обычно подгрузка модулей, их режимов и проч. К самому старту системы как бы не имеет отношения, имхо.

Comment: в файле /var/log/boot.log у меня

Comment: [^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started Network Manager Wait Online.
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Reached target Network is Online.
         Starting LSB: Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures... и так далее
         Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
         Starting Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit...
[^[[32m  OK  ^[[0m] Started LSB: Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel crash signatures.
[ ^[[31m*^[[1;31m*^[[0m^[[31m*  ^[[0m] (2 of 2) A start job is running for Wait for Plymouth Boot Screen to Quit

Comment: И когда я нажимая Esc то у меня переключается на черный экран и все